# Mystery missing 10 reputation

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

As you can all see in the screen shot below I apparently had 400 rep

[image: 400rep]

However when I went to the reputation tab on my profile page it says i have 390 rep nor is there any entry to show the reputatuon being added or removed.

[image: wheres my rep gone]

If anyone has any knowlege or ideas on this problem they would be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, a question you answered (with an answer that got an upvote) was deleted

Comment: When you go to your reputation tab (shown in your lower screenshot) and scroll to the bottom of the page, there is a *show removed posts* checkbox. If you check that and look through your reputation changes over the past few days (or since whenever you noticed you had 400 rep), does that reveal anything?

Comment: If someone upvotes, and almost immediately un-upvotes, you can have two tabs with different rep. Happens to me quite regularly. No traces are left then.

Comment: @JacobVlijm From back when you had 3800 Rep!  :D

Comment: @Fabby Those were the days :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72bPUXefB8c

Comment: @EliahKagan no it does not It only came up after i had left my computer for a while yesterday and then when I went to the rep tab to check it out it had disappeared without a trace